# Can I use regex for 'rootalias' alignment in Unison?

Tags: beyondcompare, unison

Beyond Compare has a feature called "alignment override" which allows me to specify a regex rule for matching items with different names. Folders on my destination have prefixes which I want to ignore.

For example, I can specify that a source folder called `202010_FooBar1` should be synced to destination folder `FooBar1` by specifying that `\d\d\d\d\d\d_(.*)` aligns with `$1`

The only similar option I see in unison is `rootalias` but this seems to require manually specifying every pair of folders.

Any way to do this with regex? Or is there some other tool which has this feature as well as detecting moved items?

Answer (score 1):

After using Unison for awhile now, I'm going to confidently say *No, Unison does not support such a feature*. Unison doesn't just compare files, but synchronizes them, so allowing such a feature would create syncing conflicts in many many cases.